# Common Crawl AWS public dataset transfer cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, common-crawl

I'm actually working on Common Crawl datasets and I want to know the cost of transferring data from the original S3 bucket to my EC2 cluster ? Is there any charge or it's totally free ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no charge for transferring data from S3 to EC2 within the same AWS region.  The bucket owner pays transport charges and the EC2 owner will pay a negligible cross-region data charge for the upstream traffic (essentially just the initial request, and the TCP ACKs) for downloads from S3 to EC2 in a different region.

The `aws-publicdatasets` bucket is in the us-east-1 region.

Note that you can also monitor your estimated charges with [billing alerts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-alarms.html) and avoid surprises.

Comment: Thank  you for the help :) !